# How do I make this output happen in java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I want to output the following using a for loop and subscript and I'm not sure.

output:

```
Jamaica

 amaica

  maica

   aica

    ica

     ca

      a
```

What can I do, in order to achieve this output?

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Consider `String::length` and `String::substring`

Answer (score 2):

**First:** You need to loop for generating `n` line which is the length of array.

**Second:** You need to print the spaces with is same value as `row - 1` number of times.

**Second:** You need to print character start from `row - 1` number to the length of the string.

> And the final solution will be:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void printStr(String str) {
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < str.length();i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(j = i; j < str.length();j++) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
            }
          System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass.printStr("Jamaica");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use two *regular expressions*, the first to terminate the loop when the `String` is filled with white space. The second to replace the first non-white space character with a white space in the loop body (after printing the current `String` value). And, if it's possible the `String` might be empty you should guard against that. Like,

```
String s = "Jamaica"; 
if (!s.isEmpty()) {
    while (!s.matches("\\s+")) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceFirst("\\S", " ");
    }
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
Jamaica
 amaica
  maica
   aica
    ica
     ca
      a
```

Comment: LOL, bit OTT for a beginner I think

Comment: The above loop condition might fail if string `s` was empty (I think it would loop forever).  Perhaps `while( s.matches("\\S+") )`?

Comment: @markspace You were right about the infinite loop. Added a check against that. Unfortunately the `\\S+` regex won't work beyond the initial state. So the best solution (IMO) for that edge case is an explicit guard.

Comment: I fooled around with it a bit and found that `while( s.matches( ".*\\S" ) )` seems to work. (Oops, that does not work if the string ends with a space).

Comment: Hey Rocky, want to see me pull a regex out of my hat?  `while( s.matches( ".*?\\S+.*" ) )` works in the test cases I tried...

Comment: @markspace But Bullwinkle, I just asked Mr Peabody, and he suggested `while (!s.isEmpty() && !s.matches("\\s+"))` or just `while (!s.trim().isEmpty())` - but in the given example, perhaps it's acceptable to fail on an empty string. And why optimize for the exceptional case?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.next(); //input through scanner class
    int len = s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j=i;j<len;j++){
            System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
StringBuilder country = new StringBuilder("Jamaica"); 
        for(int i=0; i< country.length();i++){
            if(i > 0)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                    country.setCharAt(j,' ');                    
                }                
            }
            System.out.println(country);            
        }
```